# SublimeText/LaTeXTools: overfull hbox warnings

Tags: warnings, sublime-text

I have recently started to use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (a text editor) and its extension package [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) (all kinds of macros that make it very convenient to edit LaTeX documents).

LaTeXTools offers a number of convenient features; for example, it parses the log files and extracts error messages.

However, it seems that some warnings are not shown. In particular, it seems that LaTeXTools does not show any "overfull hbox" warnings.

Is there any simple way to find such warnings with SublimeText/LaTeXTools? (Other than manually grepping log files.)

Comment: Knuth says not too worry about it.  It just means it is having a hard time fitting the text into lines.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, wanted an easy way to find bad boxes.  It is often necessary to correct them for publications.

The existing [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) package simply ignores the overfull/underfull warnings.  You can see this in the source file:

parseTeXlog.py: 392--415

```
392   # catch over/underfull
393   # skip everything for now
394   # Over/underfull messages end with [] so look for that
395   if line[0:8] == "Overfull" or line[0:9] == "Underfull":
      ...
415       continue
```

You have to modify that block of code so that it reports Over/Under-full messages, either as warnings, or by creating another list of messages specific for bad boxes.  I ended up forking their project and doing the latter.  You can download it [here](https://github.com/pantheras/LaTeXTools).

**Update:** Note that these changes were eventually incorporated into the official LaTeXTools package, so you can now enable them by changing the package settings as described by @Gauthier

```
{
   "display_bad_boxes": true,
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could submit that as a pull request to the main repo?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the code from the `parseTeXlog.py` file you can see that the badboxes are a third kind of error/warning. You can display the bad boxes going to `Peferences -> Package Settings -> LaTexTools -> Settings - User` and adding the following option in the setting file:

```
 {
   "display_bad_boxes": true,
 }
```

You then will have the bad boxes warnings after the usual warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [LaTeXing](http://www.latexing.com/) plugin, which prints Errors, Warnings and BadBoxes to the console when you build.

It is not free and not open source as LaTeXTools, but it offers a free unlimited trial. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173594/latexing-vs-latextools-sublime-text-plugins) offers some comparison between the two.