# LaTexing vs LaTexTools (Sublime text plugins)

Tags: luatex, workflow, sublime-text, ide

I want to use sublime as my default IDE for TeX (currently I'm using Latex Studio). I've found two great packages:

1. [LaTexTools](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LaTeXTools)
2. [LaTexing](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LaTeXing)

Both has somehow the same list of features but LaTeXing seems to have extra feature and hassle free (is it correct?). It seems support better auto complete features (esp. the citation) and better multiple PDF viewer compatibility and larger snippets (I might be wrong).

In another side, LaTexTools seems to have much larger user community and It's open source and again seems to have lots of primary features that LaTeXing has. LaTeXing isn't free (15$/user) but it has free unlimited trial and seems closed source and premium support.

I searched the web for comparison between these two, but I didn't find any proper thread. I think it could be beneficial for the users to have a good review and comparison between these two packages (to save time). What is the key differences/features between the two?

p.s.

- I'm using Linux vs ST3 ( LaTexTools didn't support ST3 some month ago and the choice was easier).
- I sometimes work with XeTeX and I like to switch to LuaTeX in the future so build systems are essential.
- I like to create TeX documents as projects and some times the projects are large so go to anything and auto complete the file names are quite handy

### Update (Apr-09-2017)

I no longer use Sublime text. Also the state of the latex support in sublime might have changed. So I've changed the approved answer.

Comment: More than a year has passed. What are you using now? I'm in the same situation as you were when you posted this question.

Comment: Me as well. @iamatrain, have you made a decision, and can you recommend one over the other?

Comment: @iamatrain Furtunately or not, I've switched to Vim...different church ;-) but the open source alternative nowadays is more mature. If you have any preference about FSF or open source so go with LaTeX Tools and  be sure about it. Otherwise if you don't have any concern regarding open source then try both, I think.

Comment: @iamatrain I think Atom editor is also a good option for those who have slight preference toward FOSS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The point of LaTeXing not being FLOSS is truly important and betting for small-scale closed-source is always risky. If the software author pulls the plug, forking by others is often not an option.

... And as it happens, look what <strike>is now</strike> WAS figuring prominently on the [LaTeXing home page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319113412/http://www.latexing.com:80/):

> 2014-06-27 16:48 by Chris
>
> <strike>The purchase of a license for LaTeXing is temporary not possible. Due
>   to personal issues the distribution is stopped and will be not
>   continued for a few month.</strike> This is not the end of LaTeXing, the
>   program will still receive updates and bug fixes during that time.

As of March 2020, the [LaTeXing github repository](https://github.com/LaTeXing/LaTeXing) has been inactive since 2015 (except for one typo in a 2018 pull request). [One fork](https://github.com/ge-gutierrezneri/LaTeXing) has some extra snippets added, otherwise all forks are inactive.

Comment: LaTeXing is back under active development. Nonetheless it's an actual risk.

Comment: The same risk is actually present in the Sublime Text editor as a whole since it is also closed source, and there have also been times when the future of Sublime Text was unsure. That being said, I still enjoy ST3 and LaTeXing far more than most alternatives out there, so for me it is worth the risk.

Comment: I think nowadays with rise of Atom editor  this answer should be updated to make it solid reasoning as Egon points it out.

Comment: Seems like the LaTeXing dev has stopped development completely now. He has put the source code [on github though](https://github.com/LaTeXing/LaTeXing), but it doesn't seem like anyone has taken on keeping the project alive (none of the forks have any commits).

Answer (score 14):

I have used both plug-ins and I am currently using LaTeXing. I will continue to do so because I find that LaTeXing has some really nifty features such as as `cmd+l,cmd+l` when including graphics or `.tex` files.

[image]

Both plug-ins do support ST3, both plug-ins support `root` directives (with some difference in the syntax, the picture above illustrates the LaTeXing `root file` syntax) and both plug-ins support projects. LaTeXing supports partial build of a project, which I'm not sure if LaTeXtools does.

However, doing a complete comparison is a tedious piece of work – the plug-ins are quite extensive. I'd recommend taking a look at the documentation of [LaTeXing](https://web.archive.org/web/20180329210203/http://docs.latexing.com:80/) and [LaTeXtools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) and finding your own preferences, as these tend to vary from one TeX personality to another.

Personally I'm still uncovering new features with LaTeXing, and I *believe* (just speculations based on a overview comparison of the [LaTeXing User Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20180329210203/http://docs.latexing.com:80/) and the [LaTeXtools documentation](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools)) that LaTeXing is a more extensive plug-in which will have a higher probability of satisfying a proper Sublimer's needs.

Comment: Yeah, I've same idea from my initial search. I'm currently installing LaTeXing...I afraid of breaking the LaTeXing by installing LaTeXTools. Fortunately you're saying it's safe to have both. However I wait for possible more elaborate comparison. My initial motivation for starting this thread is to provide a conscious comparison between the two for new users. It will save a lot of time. Just final remark, LaTeXtools is opensource and for me, personally, it's a +1!

Comment: what's your ST3 Theme?

Comment: I'm switching between Solarized (Light) and Solarized (Dark)

Comment: LaTeXtools has now the feature of Fill Helper (filling in package and file names automatically) after a recent update.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding how LaTeXing's closed/open-source status figures into the comparison:  In late 2017, LaTeXing was made free (as in beer), with a promise that it will soon be open source:

[LINK REMOVED AS OLD SITE IS ABANDONED / HIJACKED] The code is open source on GitHub and should be available via package.io (see below). For old documentation see wayback https://web.archive.org/web/20180329210203/http://docs.latexing.com:80/

(In late Sep 2017, this page says: "In the next couple of weeks the source code will become available and the community can continue to improve the package together.")

The Package Control web site lets you track the popularity of various Sublime packages. The following search URL will show you the total downloads for both LaTeXTools and LaTeXing (clicking on the name of each package will show the download history):

https://packagecontrol.io/search/latex

Right now, LaTeXTools has nearly 3x the total downloads of LaTeXing, and LaTeXTools has been about twice as popular in recent months.  Perhaps the planned move of LaTeXing to open-source is motivated by this.

The posts here from 2014, and the few blog entries I've been able to find comparing these packages, note that LaTeXTools lacked command completion and project management. However, the current LaTeXTools documentation indicates both capabilities have been added.

So far I have done only a simple comparison, with a single .tex file (i.e., not a project), on macOS Sierra.  Both packages have a "Check system" command, and all necessary tools were located by both packages.  LaTeXing had no trouble building the file and automatically launching the Skim PDF previewer. But I could not do an inverse search from the PDF back to the .tex source.  I spent some time looking online for a fix, but didn't find anything helpful. LaTeXing has a GitHub page, just hosting an issue tracker, but this issue wasn't addressed there; in fact, there is very little developer activity there.  In contrast, LaTeXTools worked fine out-of-the-box, with the source/PDF link working in both directions.  Also, I'm finding the LaTeXTools documentation to be better, and there is much more activity on GitHub.  For now, I'm sticking with LaTeXTools.

Comment: Great!  At the moment it seems the main difference to choose between these two have been the open source community and this seems to be changed in the future.  The question and the approved answer are gonna be outdated, by this move. I might wait to such open source migration happens then change approved answer. A detail comparison of main differences is absolutely welcome. Unfortunately I've moved from ST3 as my editor but still wiling to see if there is any gap between these two.

Comment: [LaTeXing has now been made open source](https://github.com/LaTeXing/LaTeXing). But it doesn't seem like there is any active development (neither on the main repo, or on any of the forks), so I'm having issues with Mendeley integration (due to changes in how the Mendeley API works, I think).